# How to test Resque worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, backgroundworker, amazon-sqs, resque

Within my rails app, I have a worker that is reading an AWS SQS and then simply enqueues another worker onto Resque.  I'm looking for the best way to test this with RSpec.

Is there a way to look to see what is on a mock Resque queue?  Basically, I just want a test that tests whether calling the SQS worker results in a Resque worker.

Answer (score 1):

Are you also using Resque to read from SQS? If so, you can use an `around` hook to enable Resque's inline mode. (This way Resque executes the jobs right away without actually queueing them.)

```rb
around do |example|
  Resque.inline = true
  example.run
  Resque.inline = false
end
```

Based on your code, you could then either check to see if the other worker has done its job (e.g. if it has created a record by checking the related records' count difference), or you could just use RSpec's [have_received](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies) method to make sure the other worker has been queued by Resque.

```rb
  allow(Resque).to receive(:enqueue)
  SQSWorker.perform
  expect(Resque).to have_received(:enqueue).with(
    OtherWorker,
    optional: 'args'
  )
```